# Unable to remove top bar for iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I have tried almost all the answers but I can't get it to work.

What I have tried so far.

Target/Generar/Deployment Info: Status Bar Style -> Light, Hide status bar checked.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
      return YES;
}
```

and

> Status bar is initially hidden = YES
>
> View controller-based status bar appearance = NO

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the view controller in which you are saying this:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
      return YES;
}
```

...is not the view controller that is consulted with regard to the status bar's visibility. That view controller is the *top-level* view controller: the ultimate root view controller. Your view controller is just a *child* of that view controller, so your `prefersStatusBarHidden` is never called.

Comment: So which is the ultimate root view controller?

Comment: I have no idea. Only you know that. You didn't say anything about what your view controller hierarchy is. If you want specific help, provide specific information. You asked why your code had no effect, and I answered that: I think it has no effect because it isn't being called. You can put a breakpoint to confirm whether I'm right about that.